# Can I pay kicker on a creature put into play with Kaalia's ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've attacked with [Kaalia of the Vast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kaalia%20of%20the%20Vast) and I decide to use her triggered ability to put [Desolation Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Desolation%20Angel) onto the battlefield. Do I get the opportunity to pay for the kicker and destroy my opponents lands? Or does it come into play and blow up my own lands?

Answer (score 7):

Kicker is an additional cost that can be paid as you're *casting* a spell, which you an see from the reminder text on Desolation Angel:

> Kicker {W}{W} (You may pay an additional {W}{W} as you cast this spell.)

You can only pay it when you're casting Desolation Angel. If it's being put directly onto the battlefield, like with Kaalia's ability, it's not being cast, so you can't pay the kicker cost, and it'll destroy only your lands.